# Start Vmware tools in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, vmware

I have build and installed vmtools from source in my bit Centos 7, but have no idea how to make it run. I have files in  `/usr/local/bin` :

```
VGAuthService  vmware-checkvm             vmware-hgfsclient     vmware-rpctool      vmware-user               vmware-vgauth-cmd        vmware-xferlogs
vmtoolsd       vmware-guestproxycerttool  vmware-namespace-cmd  vmware-toolbox-cmd  vmware-user-suid-wrapper  vmware-vgauth-smoketest
```

I also have file `/usr/local/etc/xdg/autostart/vmware-user.desktop` with content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=/usr/local/bin/vmware-user-suid-wrapper
Name=VMware User Agent
# KDE bug 190522: KDE does not autostart items with NoDisplay=true...
# NoDisplay=true
X-KDE-autostart-phase=1
```

Ho to make vmware tools run? How to know it is running?
System restart not helped - I can't copy/paste from/ro host machine.

UPD

ps faux | grep vm

output:

```
croot 487 0.0 0.3 25140 7316 ? Ss 03:13 0:00 /usr/sbin/lvmetad -f g 26876 0.0 0.0 4952 908 pts/0 S+ 07:31 0:00 \_ grep --color=auto vm
```

UPD

I was following build [manual](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/) while building and installing tools

```
autoreconf -i
./configure --without-kernel-modules
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: If you install vmware tool with this procedure http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/CentOS_7.html#Tools you should be able to just know with `ps faux | grep vm` you should see an entry with openvm tools

Comment: output of `ps faux | grep vm` in UPD

Comment: please [edit] your question instead of putting useful information inside comments.

Comment: also how did you install the vmware tools ?

Comment: I have comments in UPD regarding build and install

Comment: why not just use the version package for your OS ?

Comment: I couldn't find package for 32 bit Centos 7